# Using wp_login_form passowrd as undefined

Tags: login

Hi I am using the wp_login_form function and when it displays the password field always displays the word undefined. If I remove that when logging in the form works fine. Anyone know why this placeholder value is there no matter what instance I use it in (page, post,theme)

Thanks.

Comment: The label for the password field read undefined? Or the password defaults to undefined?

Comment: The password defaults to undefined.

Comment: How are you able to read the password? Shouldn't it be ****'s or something?

Comment: All I did was put wp_login_form function in a div and in the password field box it shows up UNDEFINED. Then I put my cursor in there to clear the box out and yes my password does show as *****. No problem with that part. I am just trying to figure out where the UNDEFINED is coming from as a default in the box.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I found out that it was coming from jquery-placeholder script I was running. Once commented out the undefined went away.

Comment: Add your own solution and mark the question as solved! Glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've got something weird going on with your wordpress install, that's coming from something that's not wordpress, value for both username and password is set to `''` in the source, there's not even anything that could be done with hooks to cause that. I suggest you look in different browsers, etc and I bet the problem will not persist.

Answer (score -1):

A jquery-placeholder script was causing the undefined to show in the password field. I kept the script but went into general-template.php in wp-includes and added holder="" to the code for the wp_login_form function password field.

Comment: Congratulations! You’ve successfully created a **fork** of WordPress which you cannot update anymore. Why didn’t you use a filter?